# чем заменить способ передвижения через gameObject.position

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в игре для передвижения обьекта используеться примерно вот такой код в апдейте
gameObject.position = новой позиции

но с таким кодом часто возникает проблема с тем, что обьеут просто проходит сквозь другие обьекты

также у меня есть обьект который использует rigidbody.AddForse() он сквозь другие обьекты не проходит

как сделать так чтобы первый обьект не проходил через другие обьекты но при этом двигался также, тоесть мгновенное ускорение, мгновенные повороты и мгновенная остановка, с аддфорс это не прокатывает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddForce` прокатит, но с `VelocityChange`, а не `Impulse`. [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html)

Либо контролировать `Rigidbody.velocity` мануально.

Если это персонаж, то нужно использовать [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/class-CharacterController.html).

Comment: Нет, это не персонаж, вернее не совсем персонаж, это бот который должен в точности следовать за его движениями. А можно хоть приблизительный пример кода, как использовать VelosityChange. В мануале глянул и ничего не понял